# Softbricked phone

Tags: unbricking, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Alright, so I used [this tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/att-galaxy-s5/general/how-to-root-g900aucu2aoa1-4-4-4-2-3-2015-t3021120) and after step 3 no my phone only boots up and says "Firmware upgrade encountered an issue. Please select recovery mode in Kies & try again"

So I tried installing the stock 4.4.2 and that didn't work, ended up with errors like Fused 3 > binary 1 and Something 2 > binary 1.

I should mention I got the Lollipop OTA update awhile ago, so I was all the way up to date. I'm guessing the issue here is that I'd need the stock image for the version I had before I started messing around, but as far as I can tell that's not available.

Not sure what to do here, but for now I'm completely cut off from communication so I could use some help!

I have the SM-G900A

Comment: The link meets the dead end: 404 not found. Please [edit].

Comment: I _think_ it's [this page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/att-galaxy-s5/general/how-to-root-g900aucu2aoa1-4-4-4-2-3-2015-t3021120). I've submitted an edit.

Comment: Yeah you guys are right about the link. Also, I ended up bringing my phone into a Samsung guy and he fixed it. From what I read maybe wiping and rewriting the partion was the fix.